# Will new version of iOS support Objective-C?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, swift, ios8

I have developed an application for `ios7` using `Objective-C`. Its in development phase now. As apple has announced new programming language `swift`. Will it replace `objective-c` or both we can use for future development?

I tried to check any update about this, but couldn't get anything.

Comment: Objective-C will be around for a while yet. Swift and Objective-C code can reside in the same binary. Your current code will continue to work in iOS 8.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C will still be around for quite a while. Apple did not deprecate the language, but it has declared that Swift will be the future of iOS development.

[Source](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11): 
*Swift Programming Guide, Page 2*

> we can now introduce a new language for the future of Apple software development.

Comment: I don't disagree but since you have said that Apple have declared that swift will be the future. Don't you think you should back this up with some evidence, such as the documentation it is written in.

Comment: Please include this in your answer as evidence not in the comments. Also note that this is from AppleInsider not officially from Apple Documentation or Apple themselves.

Comment: I agree that objective-c will be there for some time. but what will be the better for more feasible solution for past development. should we keep it in objective-c or migrate to swift ?

Comment: @I-droid currently that will just generate opinion based answers.

Comment: Updated. You're last comment is an opinion answer, so this could spawn some debate, but I am planning to do as much swift as possible, to avoiding refactoring down the road.

Comment: Apple has a migration guide which means one should migrate if they can. But yes, it's going to be around for a while

Answer (score 1):

### YES.

With the iOS 8 Beta, Objective-C-Only project works.

Though as **Matthew notes**, you should slowly adapt to Swift.

*I would not start a new project in Objective-C though, if there aren't very good reasons for it.*

You can have Objective-C code side by side with Swift code and should [migrate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH12-XID_67) code to the new programming language. So it is possible to use the *old* Objective-C frameworks/files in a *new* Swift project.

You could even use almost C Code, but that is mostly making the project more complex. The same goes with Objective-C and Swift.